# In Django, how to keep form1 data after submitting form2?

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, forms, post

In my Django view, I have defined form1 where user can select conditions to filter data that will appear at the right on my web page. In my html file, I have defined form2 that contains a datatable (with an ajax call for the contents) with checkboxes and a submit button.

So I filter data with form1 (ex: men, age>50), I check some rows on filtered data and submit the selection. The problem is after submit, the conditions specified in form1 are not saved and the data at the right is not filtered anymore. How could I keep the conditions in form1 and the filtered data after submit of form2?

My view:

```
def entite_new_list(request):
   form1 = EntiteNewFilterForm()
   data = reverse('entite_new_list_json')
   if request.method == 'GET':
        params = request.GET
   if request.method == 'POST' and request.is_ajax:
        params = request.POST
        from_form2 = 'f2' in params and params['f2']=='1'
        if from_form2:
           # process the checked rows
           # conditions formulated before in form1 are lost
        else:
           # simply refresh filtered data by sending httpresponse to ajax call
           # Create the URL query string and strip the last '&' at the end.
           data = ('%s?%s' % (reverse('entite_new_list_json'), ''.join(
              ['%s=%s&' % (k, v) for k, v in params.iteritems()])))\
              .rstrip('&')
           return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data), content_type='application/json')   

   data = ('%s?%s' % (reverse('entite_new_list_json'), ''.join(
       ['%s=%s&' % (k, v) for k, v in params.iteritems()])))\
       .rstrip('&')

   context = RequestContext(request)
   context.update(csrf(request))
   return render_to_response(
    'entites/entite_new_list.html',
    {'form1': form1, 'data': data},
    context_instance=context,
)
```

My html:

```
<!-- form1: conditions to filter data -->
<div id="collapseBody" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
   <div class="panel-body">
        {% crispy form1 %}
   </div>
</div>
...
<!-- form2: filtered data with checkboxes-->
<form id="form2" action="." method="post">
   {% csrf_token %}
   <div style="text-align:right; padding-bottom:1em;">
       <button type="submit">Submit</button>
   </div>
   <table id="entite_table" class="table-striped">
      <thead> // heading data ... </thead>
   </table>
 </form>
 ...
 <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {
       var oTable = $('#entite_table').dataTable( {
         ...
         "sAjaxSource": "{{ data }}"
       });

       var frm2 = $('#form2');    
       frm2.submit( function() {
          var csrftoken = this.csrfmiddlewaretoken.value;
          var checks = oTable.$('input').serialize();
          $.redirect("{% url 'entite_new_list' %}", {'checks':checks, 'csrfmiddlewaretoken':csrftoken, 'f2':1});
          return false;
       } );

       var frm1 = $('#new_filter_form');
       frm1.submit(function () {
         $.ajax({
            type: frm1.attr('method'),
            url: frm1.attr('action'),
            data: frm1.serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
               oTable.fnReloadAjax(data);
            },
         });
         return false;
       });
```

Can anyone help me with that?
Regards,
Patrick

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [Form Wizard](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/formtools/form-wizard/) can help you process these two forms.

Comment: Thank for the hint. Form Wizard seems to imply though a specific order for the multiple forms. In my case, I could submit the form2 without having filled anything in the form1 before.